# Android Studio add permission check bug?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

Ok, I have the following code and warning in AS:
[image]

When I agree to add such check, AS insert following code:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return TODO;
        }
```

**And I'm just wondering, why AND operator is using?**

If user reject only one of permissions above, such check wouldn't be working, as for me.

Or I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get location in different ways. Getting it from GPS using `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`, from network using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` and from `LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER` (GPS).

`permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is needed for `GPS_PROVIDER` and `PASSIVE_PROVIDER`.

`permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` is needed for `NETWORK_PROVIDER`

According to [doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/location/strategies.html):

> Note: If you are using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then
>   you need to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because
>   it includes permission for both providers. (Permission for
>   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION includes permission only for NETWORK_PROVIDER.)

So probably Android Studio does not check if you are using both, so it plays safe and checks for both

Comment: Ok, so permission check added by Android Studio, is wrong? There should be OR operator instead of AND in such case.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to check both these permissions. Even if only fine location access is denied ,the other one is automatically denied and vice versa.
Bothe comes in the same group- LOCATION
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous